# Выборка из базы данных MySQL номера строки при произвольной выборке

Tags: mysql

Есть ситуация. Есть новости скажем их 500, на разных страницах, он выводятся в разном порядке с пагинацией. И стала задача направить человека на страницу с новостью из случайного места (например с главной страницы). Т.е. необходимо получить номер строки в произвольной выборке mysql запроса при известном id новости.

Скажем выбирали по дате, и в выборке из 500 строк, нужная нам новость на 167 месте. А если по времени и записавшему, это 250 строка в ВЫБОРКЕ.

Можно это сделать mysql запросом, или придется перебирать всю выборку в поисках ?

Comment: Если выборка происходит "при известном id новости.", то в чем тогда проблема?

Comment: В MySQL вроде как нельзя получить номер записи, но можно [сымитировать](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5ac/28)

Кроме того - вас же устроит не номер текущей записи, а количество элементов до этой записи. Поэтому можно предложить следующий [вариант](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5ac/36)

Answer (score 2):

вынесено из комментариев.

---

В MySQL вроде как нельзя получить номер записи, но можно сымитировать:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5ac/28)

**MySQL 5.5 Schema Setup**:

```
drop table if exists `table`;
create table `table` (
  `f_id` int(10) null default null,
  `f_value` int(10) null default null,
  `f_count` int(10) null default null
);

INSERT INTO `table` VALUES
  (1, 1, 5), (2, 3, 4), (3, 5, 3), (4, 2, 1), (5, 4, 2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
-- simple example
SET @a := 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5ac/28/0)**:
**Query 2**:

```
SELECT (@a := @a + 1) AS `f_order_id`, `t1`.*
FROM `table` AS `t1`

WHERE `t1`.f_value <= 4
ORDER BY `t1`.f_value
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5ac/28/1)**:

```
| f_order_id | f_id | f_value | f_count |
|------------|------|---------|---------|
|          1 |    1 |       1 |       5 |
|          2 |    4 |       2 |       1 |
|          3 |    2 |       3 |       4 |
|          4 |    5 |       4 |       2 |
```

---

Кроме того - вас же устроит не номер текущей записи, а количество элементов до этой записи. Поэтому можно предложить следующий вариант:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5ac/36)

**MySQL 5.5 Schema Setup**:

```
drop table if exists `table`;
create table `table` (
  `f_id` int(10) null default null,
  `f_value` int(10) null default null,
  `f_count` int(10) null default null
);

INSERT INTO `table` VALUES
  (1, 1, 5), (2, 3, 4), (3, 5, 3), (4, 2, 1), (5, 4, 2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
-- first query
SELECT 'first query', `t1`.*
FROM `table` AS `t1`

WHERE `t1`.f_value <= 4
ORDER BY `t1`.f_value DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5ac/36/0)**:

```
| first query | f_id | f_value | f_count |
|-------------|------|---------|---------|
| first query |    5 |       4 |       2 |
| first query |    2 |       3 |       4 |
| first query |    4 |       2 |       1 |
| first query |    1 |       1 |       5 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
-- first query with current id = 2
SELECT 'first query with current id = 2', `t1`.*
FROM `table` AS `t1`,

(SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `f_id` = 2) AS `t2`

WHERE `t1`.f_value <= 4 AND `t1`.f_value > `t2`.f_value
ORDER BY `t1`.f_value DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5ac/36/1)**:

```
| first query with current id = 2 | f_id | f_value | f_count |
|---------------------------------|------|---------|---------|
| first query with current id = 2 |    5 |       4 |       2 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
-- second query
SELECT 'second query', `t1`.*
FROM `table` AS `t1`

WHERE `t1`.f_value <= 4
ORDER BY `t1`.f_count
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5ac/36/2)**:

```
| second query | f_id | f_value | f_count |
|--------------|------|---------|---------|
| second query |    4 |       2 |       1 |
| second query |    5 |       4 |       2 |
| second query |    2 |       3 |       4 |
| second query |    1 |       1 |       5 |
```

**Query 4**:

```
-- second query with current id = 5
SELECT 'second query with current id = 5', `t1`.*
FROM `table` AS `t1`,

(SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `f_id` = 5) AS `t2`

WHERE `t1`.f_value <= 4 AND `t1`.f_count < `t2`.f_count
ORDER BY `t1`.f_count
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5ac/36/3)**:

```
| second query with current id = 5 | f_id | f_value | f_count |
|----------------------------------|------|---------|---------|
| second query with current id = 5 |    4 |       2 |       1 |
```

**Query 5**:

```
-- third query
SELECT 'third query', `t1`.*
FROM `table` AS `t1`

WHERE `t1`.f_value <= 4 AND `t1`.f_count <= 4
ORDER BY `t1`.f_count
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5ac/36/4)**:

```
| third query | f_id | f_value | f_count |
|-------------|------|---------|---------|
| third query |    4 |       2 |       1 |
| third query |    5 |       4 |       2 |
| third query |    2 |       3 |       4 |
```

**Query 6**:

```
-- third query with current id = 2
SELECT 'third query with current id = 2', `t1`.*
FROM `table` AS `t1`,

(SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `f_id` = 2) AS `t2`

WHERE `t1`.f_value <= 4 AND `t1`.f_count <= 4 AND `t1`.f_count < `t2`.f_count
ORDER BY `t1`.f_count
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5ac/36/5)**:

```
| third query with current id = 2 | f_id | f_value | f_count |
|---------------------------------|------|---------|---------|
| third query with current id = 2 |    4 |       2 |       1 |
| third query with current id = 2 |    5 |       4 |       2 |
```